# using powershell, I need to append a date in a csv at the end of each entry

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm using powershell v2 on an old 2003 server so there are limitations,
all I need is to append using "add-content" to add "get-date -format t"  to the end of an entry as its entered from a script the command resides in. So far all I get is This "䜬瑥䐭瑡൥" and not the Hour and minute time output that I want to append into the file. here is my code:

Add-Content c:\Alert-2.csv ",Get-Date -format t"

The comma before Get-Date is for the csv format

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to add a line to the end of the file or add a column to every line of the csv file?

Comment: I am trying to append a column to every line of the csv file as it is updated by the script that is creating and updating it.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this:

```
import-csv C:\Alert2.csv | foreach-object {
  $row = $_
  $row | add-member NoteProperty "Time" (get-date t)
  $row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, this gets appended to my file: ",Get-Date -format t", which is expected. I am not sure why in your case "䜬瑥䐭瑡൥" gets appended. If I had to guess, I'd guess it's a problem with encoding.

As far as the code goes, consider this:

```
Add-Content c:\Alert-2.csv ",$(Get-Date -format t)"
```

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: This also works but the output is essentially this ;
ㄬ㨰㌲䄠്《ഀ਀Ⰰ〱㈺″䵁਍0

I suspect this is the output fonts aren't being recognized by notepad